# Looking for my array to show the result in table format

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am looking to be able to click on one my checkboxes that then returns a result from my table in my database. I think i have everything correct except my query to pull the data and to show the result in table format.

```
This is my index.php file that makes the checkboxes.

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="filter.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="PhoneName" id="r1">PhoneName
    <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="8GB" id="b1">8GB 
    <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="16GB" id="g1">16GB
    <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Android" id="g1">Android
    <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Apple" id="g1">Apple
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Filter" />

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my filter.php where the PHP codes starts

```
    <?php

         mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("James") or die (mysql_error());
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM hardware';
    $query=array();
    if (isset($_POST['option'])){
       foreach ($_POST['option'] as $opt){
          switch ($opt){
             case 'PhoneName':  $query[] = "PhoneName='yes'";
             case '8GB': $query[] = "8GB='yes'"; 
             case '16GB': $query[] = "16GB='yes'"; 
             case 'Android': $query[] = "Android='yes'"; 
             case 'Apple': $query[] = "Apple='yes'";
    }

          }
        }

    if (count($query)>0){
      $sql .= 'WHERE '.implode(' IN ', $query);
      print_r($_POST['option']);
    }
```

Any help would be grateful as i  have spent days making various different code but this is as far as i can get right now. i have only begun learning php a few days ago so i realize it may not be too great

Comment: id should be unique for all checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

use `break` after switch case also replace `implode(' IN ', $query)` to `implode(' OR ', $query)` OR `implode(' AND ', $query)`

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM hardware';
    $query=array();
    if (isset($_POST['option'])){
       foreach ($_POST['option'] as $opt){
          switch ($opt){
             case 'PhoneName':  $query[] = "PhoneName='yes'";
              break;
             case '8GB': $query[] = "8GB='yes'"; 
              break;
             case '16GB': $query[] = "16GB='yes'"; 
              break;
             case 'Android': $query[] = "Android='yes'"; 
              break;
             case 'Apple': $query[] = "Apple='yes'";
         }

      }
  }

    if (count($query)>0){
      $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' OR ', $query);
    }

    echo $sql;
```

see [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ehu-cba)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("James") or die (mysql_error());
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM hardware';
$query=array();
if (isset($_POST['option'])){
foreach ($_POST['option'] as $opt){
    if($opt=='PhoneName')
    $query[] = "PhoneName='yes'";        
    if($opt=='8GB')
    $query[] = "8GB='yes'"; 
    if($opt=='16GB')
    $query[] = "16GB='yes'"; 
    if($opt=='Android')
    $query[] = "Android='yes'"; 
    if($opt=='Apple')
    $query[] = "Apple='yes'";


    }
}

if (count($query)>0){
$sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $query);
print_r($_POST['option']);
echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Harish Singh. When i use your code and click on PhoneName i am getting a result of SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE PhoneName='yes'. How can i get this to pull data from my database to show results in a table format?